# How to check if version number is version between two version numbers

Tags: c#, tfs

I am doing quite a not-too-crazy project related to TFS automation.
Recently I had a discussion how and what is the most effective way to check if my version number (Major, Minor, HF, Build) - VersionToCheck has been released between versions SourceVersion and TargetVersion.

As a result, we have finished with very crazy alg:

- cv - version to check
- sv - source version
- tv - target version

  if(c1.Major >= sv.Major and <= tv.Major)
    {
    //... check minor and rest parts
    } else 
    {
    return false;
    }

As a result, we should get true/false in build number is between those two builds. To make it harder we don't have replicated numbers like 0001.0002.0003 so replace and comparing two ints won't work :)

Any tips are appreciated.

Ok to make more clear.
For example I want to check if version 1.0.44.4736 is between versions
1.0.44.11 and 1.1.0.5.

Comment: Use the [`Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.7.2) class

Comment: Version class allows you to compare Version number to version number not to check if given version number is between two versions.

Comment: Right, and to check whether a version number is between two versions, you compare it against the first and then against the second...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [`Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.7.2) class - someone else has already written the logic for you.

```
var c1 = new Version(major, minor, build, revision);
var sv = new Version(major, minor, build, revision);
var tv = new Version(major, minor, build, revision);

if (c1 >= sv && c1 <= tv) ....
```

To take your specific example

> Ok to make more clear. For example I want to check if version 1.0.44.4736 is between versions 1.0.44.11 and 1.1.0.5.

```
var c1 = new Version(1, 0, 44, 4736);
var sv = new Version(1, 0, 44, 11);
var tv = new Version(1, 1, 0, 5);
if (c1 >= sv && c1 <= tv)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c1 + " is between " + sv + " and " + tv); 
}
```

[Run it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2CtVIh).

---

If you *really* want to implement this yourself...

```
public static int Compare(Version x, Version y)
{
    int result = x.Major.CompareTo(y.Major);
    if (result != 0)
        return result;
    result = x.Minor.CompareTo(y.Minor);
    if (result != 0)
        return result;
    result = x.Build.CompareTo(y.Build);
    if (result != 0)
        return result;
    result = x.Revision.CompareTo(y.Revision);
    return result;
}
```

Then

```
if (Compare(c1, sv) >= 0 && Compare(c1, tv) <= 0) ...
```